# How to share a job from static html page to facebook or twitter or linkedin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

Hi I am posting some jobs in my career page implemented a static web page using html, css there  is no back end functionality part for that. I need to share those jobs to Facebook or twitter or linked in by clicking on those button can any one help me how to add share option to job portals.Here is the fiddle link

```
<div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
                  <span class="digit">Digital Marketing Associate</span>
                  <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
                  <div class="moreinfo accordion" >More Info</div>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>                                     
                            <h3 class="job">Roles and Responsibilities</h3>
                            <ul class="rolesand">                                   
                                <li class="rolesandres">Responsibility for hands on interaction within social media sites such as facebook, twitter etc.</li>
                                <li class="rolesandres">Responsibility for hands on interaction with off-site social properties ; other people blogs, other company facebook fan pages,forums etc.</li>                                 
                            </ul>
                 <h3 class="job">How to apply</h3>
                            <p class="howtoapp">Email us your resume along with your Linkedin profile on  ></a> Alternatively, you can also apply via <img src="image/testimonial/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" /></p>

                            <h3  class="job">Share this job</h3>
                            <p>
                            <img src="image/career page/facebook.png" alt="facebook" class="careerfacebook"/>
                            <img src="image/career page/twitter.png" alt="twitter" class="careertwitter" />
                            <img src="image/career page/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" class="careerlinkedin"/>
                            <img src="image/career page/whatsapp.png" alt="whatsapp"  class="careerwhatsapp"/>
                            <img src="image/career page/email.png" alt="email" class="careeremail" /></p>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: `clicking on those button` - start by making buttons that can be clicked, I guess

Comment: Try reading the documetation of the social networks and do a web search on this topic. This isn't a tutorial service and researching this is not difficult

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating mailer and want simple link to share you URLs.

Here are sample share links

```
/*Facebook Share*/
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//yourpage.com">Share on Facebook</a>

/*Twitter Share*/
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=This%20is%20Awesome%20page!!%20http%3A//yourpage.com">Share on Twitter</a>

/*Google Plus*/
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A//yourpage.com">Share on Google+</a>

/*LinkedIn*/
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A//yourpage.com&title=Title%20of%20your%20Page&summary=Optional%20Summary&source=http%3A//yoursource.com">Share on LinkedIn</a>

/*What's App from Mobile*/
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>

/*Email*/
<a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com?&subject=Your Subject&body=your%20mail%20content">Send Email</a>
```

Comment: But there are so many job posts for everyone there is share button then how can share only that particular post